# Are there significant reasons not to use safe navigation for every object reference?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I've been introducing some new C# language features to my team - safe navigation is one of those.

Are there any significant performance reasons to avoid usage of safe navigation for every single object/property call?

e.g.:

```
myObject?.Field?.FieldValue
```

vs.

```
myObject.Field.FieldValue
```

I know this makes it so every field is null checked - but outside of a tight loop, don't the bugs this catches make it worth it?  Or does this encourage lazy coding?

EDIT:

I found an [entire article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/05/11/3-misused-of-operator-in-c-6/) on this topic, hopefully it is helpful for others!

Comment: Side note: word choice - "catches" usually not used in "hides/protects against" meaning... NRE is better to catch bug when some field is unexpectedly null.

Comment: This assumes null is a valid and expected state for any of these objects, is that inline with your business rules?

Comment: @DaveShaw unfortunately, that is the reality of most C# code.  `null` is the default state for objects.

Comment: This is basically `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`.

Comment: The safe navigation mainly gives bad developers an excuse to write bad code (kind of how most javascript code is written). You should use it rarely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> don't the bugs this catches make it worth it?

Quite on the contrary: applying safe navigation everywhere would *hide* bugs, rather than *catching* them.

Navigating a `null` reference by mistake is a bug in the implementation which could mean one of two things:

1. A field from which you navigate was not supposed to be `null`
2. You forgot to `null`-check a field that is legitimately `null`

Applying safe navigation is a good choice for case #2, because it lets you perform null check with less code. However, it is a poor choice for case #1, because it lets the object or a variable remain in a state that is incorrect from the standpoint of your program's logic.

That is why programmers should use their discretion when applying safe navigation, deciding each case individually.

Comment: Great answer, just what I was looking for as general guidelines.  Thanks!

Comment: The safe navigation is like applying try/catch/continue to your code, mainly results in terrible non-secure confusing code. I personally try not to use it at all. if a field can be null, just check it for null and return (guard clause) or handle the null, etc... use the operator rarely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't safely Navigate when

1) Null is actually an invalid logic for what you're doing

```
public string ProcessHash(User user) 
{
    var hash = user?.Password?.Hash
    ...
}
```

It's called Safe Navigation not Easy Null Check for a reason. Imagine you're destined to read the code above.
Does ProcessHash expect the user parameter as a null argument? If so, is the Password property of it also supposed to become null? How would you know if the previous coder has used "?." instead of "." just because he's a fan of Elvis? you'd have to analyse the whole code to find out.

2) Null is having another meaning than an unavailability in your code

What does a blind man see? Darkness? Or simply nothing?

What is an empty grocery basket?

```
// This is a good
Basket<Grocery> basket = new Basket<Grocery>();
var count = basket.Count(); // returns 0

// This smells bad!
Basket<Grocery> basket = null
var count = basket?.Count ?? 0;
```

3) You're using ?. and extension methods as a pipeline operator!

Don't use ?. to chain Properties and Methods together just because it reduces the lines you write and makes your code cool. there's lots of more well thought  high level abstractions behind pipelines in fancy functional codes you see in other languages.

```
var resp = this.Bind<IceCreamDTO>()?.Validate()?.ToEntity()?.Insert()?.ToResponse();
```

There's 2 thing wrong with kind of code above.

Imagine if there was an error while validating the bound object. can you return what was wrong with it to the requester? well you can... but it's bad.

```
// That's not how this works. that's not how any of this works.
try 
{
    var resp = this.Bind<IceCreamDTO>()?.Validate()?.ToEntity()?.Insert()?.ToResponse();
    ...
} catch (ValidationException exp) 
{
     return exp.Errors.ToResponce();
}
```

well not clearly in the example above(realize it's all method calls not property calls), this also might break encapsulation principles if you're Navigating methods and properties together.

```
// Privacy violation
bool passwordValidation = user?.Password?.Hash?.Validate(hash);

// Property Security
bool passwordValidation = PasswordHash.Validate(user, hash);
```